# Storing image and information into database and retrieve using MySql Query to display using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store some information in the form and the image into database.

For Example:

```
    <form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="do_send.php">
  <label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
  </label>

<label>

  <input type="text" name="age" id="age" />
  </label>


  <label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
  </label>

  <label>
  <input type="file" name="my_file" />
  </label>
  <label>

  <input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit" />
  </label>
</form>
```

I want to store all this into database.I can store the data in the database but don't know how to store image. Kindly tell me how can i do this??

Also i want to display the data and image on another page using MySql query.

How can i do both these tasks. I am limited knowledge as i am a starter. Please guide me with code and a little bit of explanation.

Comment: very easy, google it, `how to insert data into database with mysqli prepare statement` when you done, then search `upload file and store in database` when done then search `fetch data and display using php mysqli` i bet you will find 100's of tutorials

Comment: by the way MySql query is deprecated so if you want to learn, learn mysqli or PDO

Comment: And if you are at it: Change from MySQL to MariaDB drop-in replacement.

Answer (score 0):

use move_uploaded_file() function

create new folder in php project directory to store images.

only store path of image in database.

`$fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]; 
    $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];
    $pathAndName = "uploads/".$fileName;
    $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $pathAndName);`

store $pathAndName variable value in database.
"uploads"  is a folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Use [buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) + [imagepng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php).

In `do_send.php` you can try with something like this :

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($my_file);

// start buffering
ob_start();
imagepng($image);
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$str_base64_img = base64_encode($contents);

imagedestroy($image);
```

---

In my opinion, it's not a good pratice to directly store image datas in db and base64_encode enlarge to 33% your datas.

You should be used an hosting image system and store the path to the image in your db.